# Returning a set of indices where there is a match between two lists

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists:

```
>>list_a=[(a,b),(b,c),(e,d),(w,z)]
>>list_b=[(f,g),(e,d),(w,z)]

>>compare_lists(list_a,list_b)
would output  [(2,1),(3,2)]
```

where we see (e,d) is a matching element in
both lists and 2 is its index in list_a and 1 is its index in list_b and by similar logic for (w,z) we get (3,2). How would I go about
achieving the above? I am essentially trying to get a list of the ordered pairs of the index of list_a and list_b where there is a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary keyed by the ordered pairs in the first list, then iterate over the second list, checking against the dictionary:

```
list_a=[('a','b'),('b','c'),('e','d'),('w','z')]
list_b=[('f','g'),('e','d'),('w','z')]

d = {p:i for i,p in enumerate(list_a)}
matches = [(d[p],i) for i,p in enumerate(list_b) if p in d]

print(matches) #[(2, 1), (3, 2)]
```